# Azure Search - Find matches within a word like "contains"

Tags: azure, lucene, search-engine, azure-cognitive-search

I use Azure Search which in turn uses Lucene. Is there any way to make search not that strict.
What I need is when searching for "**term**" should match documents with terms that contain "**term**".

Serching fox **term** should match "Prefix**Term**", "**Term**Suffix", "Prefix**Term**Suffix"

Serching fox **part2** should match "part1**part2**", "**part2**part3", "part1**part2**part3"

I need to run search query which has several terms like

```
"term part2"
```

To match documents like:

```
{ someField:"... PrefixTermSuffix ... part1part2part3 ..." }
{ someField:"... PrefixTerm ... part2part3 ..." }
etc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use regex expression in Lucene query syntax in Azure Search. In your example, you can construct a regex query like /.*term.*/ /.*part2.*/ to find the documents with terms that contains the two search terms as substrings.

https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[search index]/docs?api-version=2016-09-01&queryType=*full*&search=*/.*term.*/ /.*part2.*/*

Azure Search supports two query syntaxes, simple and full. The latter enables the Lucene query syntax. Please see our documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search) to learn more about the capabilities.