# How to search based on field in azure search?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

i am using a azure search, and i have a console app with  the code as below, which is working fine.

```
        DocumentSearchResult<Hotel> results;
        Console.WriteLine("Search started\n"); 
        results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("smart", new SearchParameters { Top=5 });
        WriteDocuments(results);
```

currently its searching a text with word "smart". this is straight forword,  what i need is i have several fields in the table, i want to search based on the feild .

for example let i have two fields 
1)Title
2)SoldDate

I have to write code for finding items which has title 'john' and which has a sold date < current date.

what should i do to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with search and a filter:

```
// Approach #1
string currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O");
var parameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    Filter = "soldDate lt " + currentDate,
    Top = 5
}

results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("john", parameters);
```

This will filter the documents to only those with a `soldDate` before `currentDate`, and then searches the filtered documents such that documents match if any of the searchable fields contain "john". You can narrow this down to just the `title` field like this:

```
// Approach #2
string currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O");
var parameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    Filter = "soldDate lt " + currentDate,
    SearchFields = new[] { "title" },
    Top = 5
}

results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("john", parameters);
```

Or like this:

```
// Approach #3
string currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("O");
var parameters = new SearchParameters()
{
    Filter = "soldDate lt " + currentDate,
    QueryType = QueryType.Full,
    Top = 5
}

results = indexClient.Documents.Search<Hotel>("title:john", parameters);
```

Which way you use depends on whether you want all search terms to be limited to a specific set of fields (Approach #2), or if you want specific terms to match specific fields (Approach #3).

The reference for `SearchParameters` is on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.searchparameters).

Comment: what should i have to give,  if i have a field 'model' and i need to search whether model contains 100 (Like query) ?

Comment: what should i do to search tilte="john" and job="engineer" ? basically both should be like query

Comment: @hildasonica You've asked this question elsewhere, so I will try to answer it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510832/how-to-set-a-query-for-like-query-in-azure-search-query-syntax

Comment: you didint answer it yet. im waiting for your answer

Comment: @hildasonica Now that I understand your other question, it seems it's already been answered elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893802/azure-search-find-matches-within-a-word-like-contains

Comment: its not what i expect, i am  not looking for matching 2 terms, i want to do filter. i should get results which matches both condition eg:  search result should have Title field with term " john" as well as Job field should contain  "Engineer ".

Comment: "Filter" in Azure Search means strictly matching values. For strings, this means a match is based on case-sensitive equality. This is not what you want since you're looking for "contains"-like behavior. The other answers I have pointed you to explain how to get "contains"-like behavior; Now it sounds like you need to combine different search expressions. You can do this using the AND operator. Please read about the full Lucene query syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search

Comment: @hildasonica Also, please try to avoid asking different questions in the comments as it makes it more difficult for other Stack Overflow users to find the answers. Thanks

Comment: I can see that when I add a date comparison in the filter section it works, however not in the search section.   Any suggestions on how I can boost for certain date ranges?

Comment: @nmishr Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680139/boosting-docs-based-on-date-range