# how to set a query for like query in azure search query syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying azure search from my project and i am trying the following

```
 indexClient.Documents.Search<AuctionResult>("john", new SearchParameters { IncludeTotalResultCount = true, Filter = "SoldDate ge 2017-04-06 and SoldDate le 2017-04-06 and substringof(Title, '2007')" });
```

what i need is i need to filter the result based on the field Title, if Title contains the text '2007', it should be included.

what went wrong for me, what change should i make?

Comment: What happens with this query?any error? No result? Unexpected result?

Comment: an error shows there is no function called substringof

Comment: you dont have any idea?

Comment: It means that function `substringof` is not supported when you perform search this way.

Comment: Did you try using `contains` ?

Comment: Azure Search does not support substringof or contains.

Comment: @hildasonica Can you give an example of your Title field contents? Is 2007 one of the terms in this field (e.g. "Budget 2007"), or is it part of a single term (e.g. "budget2007.xlsx")?

Comment: let title contain budget2007, how to search it out?

Comment: @hildasonica Thanks. It would help clarify things if you gave examples in your original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Search - Find matches within a word like "contains"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893802/azure-search-find-matches-within-a-word-like-contains)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at last i found the solution

so we should use the following in the query

```
search.ismatch('searchQuery',Search_feild)"
```

so

```
"SoldDate ge 2017-04-06 and SoldDate le 2017-04-06 and search.ismatch('2007','Title')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex query to search within words. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893802/azure-search-find-matches-within-a-word-like-contains) for details.