# Boosting docs based on date range

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am to be able to filter documents based on a date, but what I really need is to boost certain date ranges higher.  The following query returns results.

```
{
  "queryType":"full",
  "search": "(priority:High^50 || Normal^10) AND (type:one^1 || two^10)",
  "filter": "(type eq 'one' or type eq 'two') and publishedDate eq 2018-04-01", 
  "searchMode": "all"
}
```

But I don't really want to filter those,  I want to boost certain dates. What I really want is something like this:

```
{
  "queryType":"full",
  "search": "(priority:High^50 || Normal^10) AND (type:one^1 || two^10) AND publishedDate:2018-04-01^100",
  "filter": "(type eq 'one' or type eq 'two')", 
  "searchMode": "all"
}
```

I get an error:
    {
    "error": 
        {"code": "",
         "message": "Illegal arguments in query request: publishedDate is not a searchable field."
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at scoring profiles in Azure Search. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index. You can specify a freshness function on the datetime field and give a range of dates to boost matches.

Nate