# Azure search issue with search?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using Microsoft azure search. In it i have  query

```
"search.ismatch('{filter.Model}','Model')"
```

Here if i give

```
filter.Model=580
```

It will only show results which has 580 as a separate word,
but i want to get result which has model name 580A or 580B or ABC580.

what should i do to acheive this one?
I have even tried

```
"search.ismatchScore('{filter.Model}','Model')"
"search.ismatchScore('+{filter.Model}','Model')"
```

i am referring [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `*` as a wildcard?

```
 "search.ismatch('{filter.Model}*','Model')"
```

This will however only find values that start with your value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/simple-query-syntax-in-azure-search

If you want "*" on both sides of the expression, take a look at this:

[Azure Search - Find matches within a word like "contains"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893802/azure-search-find-matches-within-a-word-like-contains)

This describes how you can use the full query syntax and a regex expression to perform a **contains** operation using regex. Please be aware that contains means that also ABC580DEF will be matched.

Comment: ("search.ismatch('\*{filter.Model}\*','Model') this doesnt seem to be working

Comment: is azure only support starting with? what about ending with?

Comment: Please reread my answer. The wildcard only works for StartsWith. If you want "contains", take a look at the last link of my answer.

Comment: Regex queries are only supported in full query mode. You would have to specifically add an additional query parameter  called 'queryType=full'

Comment: @upasan , so how will be my query ? how can i use it in ismatch query?

Comment: something like this should work:  https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[search index]/docs?api-version=2016-09-01&queryType=full&search=/.*580.*/